# How to identify unique combinations of pairs in Excel?

Tags: excel-formula

My goal is to get a two-column array of all the possible unique pairs of N items (so N*(N-1)/2 pairs).

I have done this in the past using extra calculation columns, but with the advent of LET() I was wondering if I can get a single function call.

This is my example data:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I came up with this, which is a little unwieldy but does the job:

```
=LET(x,B2:B5,INDEX(x,LET(n,ROWS(x),s,(1+SEQUENCE((n*n*2),2))/2,r,INT((s-1)/n)+1,LET(a,IF(INT(s)=s,r,INT(s)-((r-1)*n)),FILTER(a,INDEX(a,,1)<INDEX(a,,2))))))
```